# Shade effect on ImageView

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to implement the following imageView. Notice how there is a black shade at the bottom of the imageView. How can I add this shade to an imageView using kotlin?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did u try: `android:elevation="3dp"` in ImageView xml? let try.

Hope this help!